Just getting into singing and I am wondering what I can expect my vocal range to expand to with formal training?
I am a 16 year old male and I have no training when it comes to singing so I am not sure what techniqes I am really using to achieve this range but from what I know my range is D#2 - F6.
That range is without my voice breaking or sounding terrible, I am not sure where this places me in terms of vocal group or what I can expect to have my range be with training.

Sorry, to rephrase the D#2 - F6 range is what I am able to do comfortably without strain.

Your range may or may not expand as you learn more, but even if it doesn't, D#2 - F6 is a huge range. My trained range is not big but it's fairly normal and it's about F2 - F4.

A 4octave+ range is quite unusual, male or female. Your body, thus voice, hasn't fully developed yet, so there's no knowing what will happen. Go with the flow. If you want expert advice, strangers on the net is not the place to ask. Finding a teacher is far more beneficial.
